# cakephp3 own query builder

Tags: mysql, cakephp-3.0

i'm new in cakephp, and i'm following the toutorial, i came from other languages and is not usual for me to read query like this:

```
   public function findTagged(Query $query, array $options)
    {
        $columns = [
            'Articles.id', 'Articles.user_id', 'Articles.title',
            'Articles.body', 'Articles.published', 'Articles.created',
            'Articles.slug',
        ];

        $query = $query
            ->select($columns)
            ->distinct($columns);

        if (empty($options['tags'])) {
            // If there are no tags provided, find articles that have no tags.
            $query->leftJoinWith('Tags')
                ->where(['Tags.title IS' => null]);
        } else {
            // Find articles that have one or more of the provided tags.
            $query->innerJoinWith('Tags')
                ->where(['Tags.title IN' => $options['tags']]);
        }

        return $query->group(['Articles.id']);
    }
```

This is a simple query and it's easy to understand ,but if i have a more complex query with a lot of join etc, is there the possibility to write your own query with sql sintax, can you help me translating this code to a query written in sql?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write directly execute an SQL query with `$connection->execute()` (https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#running-select-statements) but I would recommend to stick to cakephp's ORM.

If you want to know how the query that you posted above translates into SQL, I would recommend to use the DebugKit. If you have in your app configuration debug = true, you will see this red rectangle at the bottem right corner, when you open your app in the browser. Click on it and click on "Sql queries": you will find the generated SQL from the query above somewhere in there. Alternatively you could use query logging (see here: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/database-basics.html#database-query-logging)

Comment: Thank you, but i'm trying to use debugkit but i'm missing smething ; i've enabled it in application.php, but i see nothing on the page, also added code in configuration: https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/debug-kit.html

Comment: Difficult to guess what could be going on. In your config/bootstrap.php do you see this line `Plugin::load('DebugKit', ['bootstrap' => true]);` ? Is there a `debug_kit.sqlite` file in the tmp directory?

Comment: Solved! seems that you need to have a database called debug_kit